# Multiple Git repositories in Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans

Is it possible to have separate repositories for every project in Netbeans?
If yes, how to do it?
If not, how to push projects to different repositories on Github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each project has it's dedicated directory. Those are *independent* under version control.

> If yes, how to do it?

Just don't great one huge version controlled folder. Create one for each project and put that under version control. This is the default behaviour of Netbeans btw.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it, because I had just one big repository.